# Why is the conjugate of an eigenpair also an eigenpair

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is an exercise on the book fundamentals of matrix computations 1st. edition.

It asks to show that for $A \in R^{nxn}$, if $(\lambda, u)$ eigenpair, then $(\overline{\lambda}, \overline{u})$ is also an eigenpair.

Comment: It helps to note that for $A,B \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$, we have $\overline{AB} = \bar A \bar B$ (where $\bar A$ denotes the conjugate of $A$).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I am sorry, could you give me some more? I am staring at it, but I do not see it still.

Comment: If $Au = \lambda u$ then $\overline{A} \overline{u} = \overline{A u} = ?$

Answer (score 0):

$A \in R^{nxn}$ and $(\lambda, u)$ is eigenpair

$$ Au = \lambda A$$
$$\overline{Au}=\overline{\lambda A}$$
$$A\overline u=\overline\lambda A\tag{$\because A \in R^{nxn}$}$$

$\therefore (\overline\lambda, \overline u)$ is also eigenpair.

Comment: Are you going through Horn and Johnson?